# How to structure user input condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a simple tictactoe game to play in terminal and I got stuck at a point. I am trying to get the position the user would play in but if the position is already filled, I want the user to be prompted to re-enter a correct value.

I keep getting the prompt for the user to re-enter value over and over again when getPlayerPosition()  is called but it never moves on from there. How can I re-structure the getPlayerPosition() function

```js
let availablePositions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let ticTacToeObj = {
  // Define the board

  board: [
    "e", "e", "e",
    "e", "e", "e",
    "e", "e", "e"
  ],
  playerMove: function(input, position) {
    this.board[position] = input
    console.log(this.board)
  },
  player1Letter: "x",

  player2Letter: "o"

}

function getPlayerPosition() {
  let player1Position = prompt(`${player1Name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + player1Name.slice(1)} please pick a position: `);
  if (availablePositions.includes(player1Position) && ticTacToeObj.board[player1Position] !== ticTacToeObj.player1Letter && ticTacToeObj.board[player1Position] !== ticTacToeObj.player2Letter) {
    ticTacToeObj.playerMove(player1Input, player1Position);
  } else {
    getPlayerPosition();
  }
}


function player1Game() {
  let player1Input = prompt(`${player1Name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + player1Name.slice(1) } please enter \"x\": `);
  //Create an error that responds if player 1 does not type x
  if (player1Input !== ticTacToeObj.player1Letter) {
    console.log(`Please make sure you type in ${ticTacToeObj.player1Letter}`)
    player1Game();
  } else {
    getPlayerPosition();
  }
}
player1Game()
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it into a [mcve]

Comment: Hi i dont't see a snippet

Comment: Reload the page. You will see it unless you are on a mobile device

Comment: It is in a snippet. Please make the snippet run. Click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet"

Comment: How are you calling your functions?

Comment: i call player1Game function first

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but does player1Input being correctly passed to playerMove ?

```
ticTacToeObj.board[player1Position] !== ticTacToeObj.player2Letter) {
        ticTacToeObj.playerMove(player1Input, player1Position);
```

Please try passing it as an argument this way inside your player1Game

```
player1Game() {
/* your code */

getPlayerPosition(player1Input);
}
```

and in your getPlayerPosition

```
function getPlayerPosition(player1Input) {
/* Your code */
}
```